# How can I use md5 passwords in .htpasswd file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

Hi I am trying to set up a `.htaccess` and a `.htpasswd` file to see if a user can have access to a particular directory. When a new user registers, their passwords are encrypted with the PHP `md5()` function and then stored in the database with their other login info. I would like to add a few of their encrypted passwords into my `.htpasswd` file dynamically so that they can enter into a sub member section. I am having trouble because the `.htpasswd` file would work with passwords encrypted with the `crypt()` function but i am not sure how to get it to work with their md5 encrypted passwords.

Comment: Rather than writing to `.htpasswd`, have you considered using [`mod_authn_dbd`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html)?  You can use any of the [supported password formats](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/password_encryptions.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html) says:

> htpasswd encrypts passwords using either a version of MD5 modified for
>   Apache, or the system's crypt() routine. Files managed by htpasswd may
>   contain both types of passwords; some user records may have
>   MD5-encrypted passwords while others in the same file may have
>   passwords encrypted with crypt().

I think you can explicitly specify apache to use md5s for password in htpasswd file using `-m` argument to `htpasswd`

If you don't want or can't use the htpasswd tool, you can create *crypt()* based passwords from PHP:

```
$clearTextPassword = 'some password';
$password = crypt($clearTextPassword, base64_encode($clearTextPassword));
```

Answer (score 3):

"I think you can explicitly specify apache to use md5s for password in htpasswd file using -m argument to htpasswd"

I just found out the exact opposite in Ubuntu 12.04 and newer, it defaults to md5 and you have to use the -d flag to get it to use Crypt. This might be the case elsewhere too, I can't seem to find a version number for htpasswd.